# How to track latency in flink?

Tags: apache-flink

In the [doc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html#latency-tracking), it says:

> To enable the latency tracking you must set the
>   latencyTrackingInterval to a positive number in either the Flink
>   configuration or ExecutionConfig.

I do it as it says, then how can I get the latency value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latency values are job metrics, which you can access via the REST API at

```
http://localhost:8081/jobs/<job id>/metrics
```